# Bind a Timespan to a Slider

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, slider

I have an interval in my program saved as a `TimeSpan`. I want to bind the value to a Slider to easy adjust the TimeSpan. My plan was something like this but it doesn't work (it does nothing at all):

**EDIT: Changed some code based on the answers, but still i have the same problem**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    ...

TimeSpan measure_gap = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); //init
public double Measure_gap 
{
    get
    {
        return measure_gap.TotalSeconds;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != measure_gap.TotalSeconds)
        {
            measure_gap = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value);
            OnPropertyChanged("Measure_gap");
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

and here is my binding (i think the problem is here)

```
<Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="38,202,0,0" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" SmallChange="1" 
 Value="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=Measure_gap, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

So my question is, what am i doing wrong :-) thanks
edit: this..BindingContext = this

Comment: You're basically never telling the UI that your value has changed. Google for `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In this case I would personally choose to use a `DependencyProperty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's small, fully functioning example for you. Slider is TwoWay databound to MeasureGap property. TextBlock is bound to the Slider so you can see current value as you drag it.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="SliderExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="120" Width="300">  

    <Grid Margin="20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Current value:" />
                <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=MySlider, Path=Value}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <Slider x:Name="MySlider" Grid.Row="1" 
                Minimum="1" Maximum="10" SmallChange="0.5" 
                Value="{Binding MeasureGap, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Codebehind**

```
using System;

namespace SliderExample
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        TimeSpan _measureGap = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public double MeasureGap
        {
            get { return _measureGap.TotalSeconds; }
            set { _measureGap = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value); }
        }
    }
}
```

**Screencap**

[image: notfound]

Comment: exactly what i needed and very simple, perfect answer thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes the Problem is the value changed will not be updated to Binding. Here i elaborate a little,

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    TimeSpan measure_gap = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); //init
    public double Measure_gap
    {
        get
        {
            return measure_gap.TotalSeconds;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != measure_gap.TotalSeconds)
            {
                measure_gap = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value);
                OnPropertyChanged("Measure_gap");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome... Hope these things will help you in your future.. though if you thought this answer would be helpful.. mark it as answer... Thanks..

Comment: since i found no single (accpeted) solution how to bind a variable to an wpf element it seems to be a bigger problem then i thought and i cant give you an accepted answer, because my problem isn't solved yet, but you get an upvote of course for leading me in the right direction (i hope), i just decided to try the thing with the dependencyproperty instead of giving up :-) last try!

Answer (score 0):

You can either bind your slider value to a model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged (what Kevin said in comment) or instead handle ValueChanged event and retrieve new value manually.

Comment: The `Slider.Value` property binds `TwoWay` by default. This is not his issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to say what's going on with your updated code, but go ahead and try this and let me know if it works or not:

Keep what you have done from Sankarann's answer, but lets change some XAML.

At the top of your MainWindow XAML file, you should be defining your `Window` go ahead and add the following line:

```
<Window x:Class="Something.MainWindow"
        ...
        ...
        DataContext="{Binding ReletiveSource={ReletiveSource Self}}">
```

Then remove the element name from the binding in your slider:

```
<Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="38,202,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" SmallChange="1"
        Value="{Binding Measure_gap, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```